# Oracle SQL Count Function Display Only One Value

Tags: sql, oracle, function, count

I am learning SQL for a personal projects and seems that I don't quite get the COUNT function.

I have a "sample" table with this sample data:

- NAME COLOR
- Tom   red
- Tom   blue
- Jerry yellow
- Keri  yellow
- Paul  red
- Bob  yellow
- Bob   red
- Mary  green

What I am attempted to do is print out only those NAME values that have only one COLOR value which is yellow.

Here is the query I wrote but Bob is coming out, which is a mistake.

```
SELECT COUNT(NAME),NAME
FROM SAMPLE
WHERE (COLOR = 'yellow')
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
GROUP BY NAME;
```

May someone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(NAME),NAME
FROM SAMPLE
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND MAX(COLOR) = 'yellow';
```

As @paxdiablo said, you need to leave the rows in the group until *after* you do the group by, so the count will be accurate.  Then you can test for `'yellow'` in the `HAVING` clause.

Even though it may seem redundant to use `MAX()` like I did in the above example, it's good form because any expression in the `HAVING` clause should use group-oriented functions.  `HAVING` restricts groups whereas `WHERE` restricts rows.

Comment: Will that work for red? It looks like it'll only work for yellow since that's the 'maximum' color.

Comment: it will work but I think it would be a bit clearer if you COUNT(color) instead of name - just me though.  It works because the COUNT(color) = 1 limits to names with only one color.

Comment: Another suitable query could be
SELECT NAME
FROM SAMPLE
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
AND COUNT(CASE WHEN COLOR='YELLOW' THEN 1 END) = 1

This allows for variations of the query (eg to pick out people who have yellow and another colour).

Comment: @paxdiablo: If the group has a `COUNT(*)` of only one row, then `MAX(color) = MIN(color)`, so it works for any color.  The suggestions by @David and @Gary are also unnecessary.  Either the group's sole color is 'yellow' or another color or else NULL.  The condition `MAX(color) = 'yellow'` works in any of these cases.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your `where` clause is limiting the result set *before* the `having` clause is checking.

Hence you are stripping out `bob red` so that the only `bob` left is the `yellow` one. And it will have a count of 1.

This one works for me (albeit in DB2 but since I tend to prefer standard SQL, it should work on any DBMS):

```
select count(a.name), a.name
from sample a,
     (select name from sample where color = 'yellow') b
where a.name = b.name
group by a.name
having count(a.name) = 1;
```

Yellow returns (no Bob):

```
--------
   NAME 
--------
1  Jerry
1  Keri
```

while red returns (no Tom or Bob):

```
-------
   NAME
-------
1  Paul
```

The way this works is as follows:

- A subquery is run to get a list of all names that have the color yellow. They can also have other colors at this point. This restricts the names to Jerry, Keri and Bob.
- Then the "real" query is run getting the list of all names *but only when they match one of the names in the subquery* (so limiting it to names that have yellow).
- This is grouped by the name and we use the `count` aggregate function to combine rows with the same name and give us a count of the colors for each name.
- Lastly we throw away those that have more than one color.

I'm assuming here that you won't have a row in the table with a duplicate name *and* color - in other words, you should have a primary key or other constraint on (name,color). If you did have duplicates, then the cross-join would result in more rows and you would have to use `distinct` or `group by` in the subquery).

Answer (score 1):

Another method using an analytic function:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM   (
       SELECT NAME,
              COLOR,
              COUNT(*) OVER () ROWS_PER_NAME
       FROM   SAMPLE )
WHERE  COLOR = 'yellow' AND
       ROWS_PER_NAME = 1
```

Also, if very few NAME's had the color yellow I would try:

```
SELECT NAME,
       COLOR
FROM   SAMPLE P
WHERE  COLOR = 'yellow' AND
       NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT null
          FROM   SAMPLE C
          WHERE  C.NAME = P.NAME
          AND    COLOR != 'yellow')
```